How do I align the button with the center of the neon circle?
What I'm trying to do is align the fingerprint button with the center of the neon loading circle. Also, when I click the finger print button it should start the animation rather than at the start of loading page.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var circleCursor = document.createElement('div');
  circleCursor.className = 'circle-cursor';
  document.body.appendChild(circleCursor);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    circleCursor.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    circleCursor.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
    circleCursor.style.display = 'block';
    // document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this);
  });
});

const rating = document.getElementsByClassName('rating')[0];
const block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  rating.innerHTML += "<div class='block'></div>";
  block[i].style.transform = "rotate(" + 3.6 * i + "deg)";
  block[i].style.animationDelay = `${i/40}s`;
}

const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    btn[i].classList.toggle('button-clicked');
    btn[i].firstElementChild.classList.toggle('icon-clicked');
  })
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    btn[i].classList.toggle('button-hover');
  })
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    btn[i].classList.add('button-hover');
  })
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    btn[i].classList.remove('button-hover');
  })
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
body {
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(46, 44, 45, 1) 0%, rgba(66, 64, 67, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
span,
button {
  cursor: none;
}

.card {
  z-index: 100;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(#444, #222);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.card .rating {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background: #f00; */
}

.card .rating .block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animate 2s linear forwards;
  /* transform: rotate(25deg); */
}


/* .block .btn {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} */

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.card .rating .block:nth-child(-n+51) {
  background: aquamarine;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px aquamarine, 0 0 30px #0f0;
}

.card .rating h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.card .rating h2 span {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.card .rating h2 sup {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.circle-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  /* background-color: #008ECE; */
  background-color: rgb(135, 206, 235);
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  border: 4px #090909 solid;
  background: linear-gradient( 145deg, #171717, #444245);
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px #7d7c7e, inset -2px -2px 0px #1c1c1c;
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.btn span {
  font-size: 2.9em;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: linear-gradient( 145deg, #262626, #606060);
  width: 7.25em;
  height: 7.25em;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 11px 11px 22px #141414, -11px -11px 22px #525252;
}

.button-clicked {
  background: linear-gradient( -185deg, #131313, #444245;
  );
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 0px #5e5e5e, inset 2px 2px 0px #1c1c1c;
}

.button-hover {
  background: #5e5e5e;
}

.icon-clicked {
  color: #0fa;
  text-shadow: 0 0 7px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 21px #fff,
}
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fd3faaa138.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card">
  <div class="rating">
    <div class="block">
      <button class="btn">
          <span class="material-icons-outlined">
              <i class='fas fa-fingerprint'></i>
          </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Output:


Create a minimal reproducer.

Yeah, we don't need your whole codebase, just enough to chow the problem.

OK - got it. Does this include the   tags or not inclusive? Thanks

I have tried with adding position: absolute, left: -43px; & top: 50px; to .btn and it worked flawlessly without compromising hover effect or anything.
Below is example. Also this ring animation looks fire.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var circleCursor = document.createElement('div');
  circleCursor.className = 'circle-cursor';
  document.body.appendChild(circleCursor);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    circleCursor.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    circleCursor.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
    circleCursor.style.display = 'block';
    // document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this);
  });
});

const rating = document.getElementsByClassName('rating')[0];
const block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  rating.innerHTML += "<div class='block'></div>";
  block[i].style.transform = "rotate(" + 3.6 * i + "deg)";
  block[i].style.animationDelay = `${i/40}s`;
}

const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    btn[i].classList.toggle('button-clicked');
    btn[i].firstElementChild.classList.toggle('icon-clicked');
  })
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    btn[i].classList.toggle('button-hover');
  })
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    btn[i].classList.add('button-hover');
  })
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    btn[i].classList.remove('button-hover');
  })
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
body {
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(46, 44, 45, 1) 0%, rgba(66, 64, 67, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
span,
button {
  cursor: none;
}

.card {
  z-index: 100;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(#444, #222);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.card .rating {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background: #f00; */
}

.card .rating .block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animate 2s linear forwards;
  /* transform: rotate(25deg); */
}


/* .block .btn {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} */

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.card .rating .block:nth-child(-n+51) {
  background: aquamarine;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px aquamarine, 0 0 30px #0f0;
}

.card .rating h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.card .rating h2 span {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.card .rating h2 sup {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.circle-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  /* background-color: #008ECE; */
  background-color: rgb(135, 206, 235);
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
}

.btn {
      position: absolute;
    left: -43px;
    top: 50px;

  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  border: 4px #090909 solid;
  background: linear-gradient( 145deg, #171717, #444245);
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px #7d7c7e, inset -2px -2px 0px #1c1c1c;
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.btn span {
  font-size: 2.9em;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: linear-gradient( 145deg, #262626, #606060);
  width: 7.25em;
  height: 7.25em;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 11px 11px 22px #141414, -11px -11px 22px #525252;
}

.button-clicked {
  background: linear-gradient( -185deg, #131313, #444245;
  );
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 0px #5e5e5e, inset 2px 2px 0px #1c1c1c;
}

.button-hover {
  background: #5e5e5e;
}

.icon-clicked {
  color: #0fa;
  text-shadow: 0 0 7px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 21px #fff,
}
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fd3faaa138.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card">
  <div class="rating">
    <div class="block">
      <button class="btn">
          <span class="material-icons-outlined">
              <i class='fas fa-fingerprint'></i>
          </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



